# Why does (let x = x+3 in fst (snd (x+1,(5,x-2)))) equal 5

Tags: haskell

Can someone explain to me why this equals 5?

```
let x = x+3 in fst (snd (x+1,(5,x-2)))
```

Comment: What do you think it should equal, and why?

Comment: You can compute it step by step, start by replacing `snd (a,b)` with `b`...

Comment: Are you asking why it doesn't equal something else or why it doesn't produce an error?

Comment: The `fst` and `snd` do not need to evaluate the `let` expression or indeed any value for `x` at all in order to produce their result.

Answer (score 7):

Let's ignore the `let x = x + 3 in` part for now and focus on what comes after the `in`:

```
fst (snd (x + 1, (5, x - 2)))
```

With the definitions of `fst` and `snd` being

```
fst (a, b) = a
snd (a, b) = b
```

So reducing what's in the parentheses first

```
snd (x + 1, (5, x - 2)) ==> (5, x - 2)
```

Now this gets passed to `fst`:

```
fst (5, x - 2) ==> 5
```

So in the end the value of `x` doesn't actually matter.

This can happen in Haskell because of something called lazy evaluation.  Essentially, the compiler won't resolve a value until it's needed.  With the definition

```
x = x + 3
```

If you tried to print `x` you would get an infinite loop and probably an error at some point when you run out of memory trying to evaluate this.  Since the value of `x` is never actually printed out, the compiler is free to not resolve its value.  The value that is printed out to the console when you evaluate that expression in the REPL is 5, it has no dependencies on the value of `x`, so `x` can be safely ignored.

Another example of where lazy programming comes in to play is the expression

```
> let ones = 1:ones in take 5 ones
[1,1,1,1,1]
```

The definition `let ones = 1:ones` defines an infinite list of 1s, but since we only grab 5 of them with `take 5 ones`, this expression is able to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

`snd(x+1,(5,x-2))` equals to `(5,x-2)`, then `fst(5,x-2)`equals to `5`. All of this doesn't require any evaluation of expression containing `x` (Haskell is lazy, means that it evaluates things only when needed).